# How do I format a list of phone numbers using regular expression in vim commands?

Tags: regex, vim, command-prompt, backreference

Given the following list of phone numbers

```
8144658695
812 673 5748
812 453 6783
812-348-7584
(617) 536 6584
834-674-8595
```

Write a single regular expression (use vim on loki) to reformat the numbers so they look like this

```
814 465 8695
812 673 5748
812 453 6783
812 348 7584
617 536 6584
834 674 8595
```

I am using the search and replace command.  My regular expression using back referencing:

```
:%s/\(\d\d\d\)\(\d\d\d\)\(\d\d\d\d\)/\1 \2 \3\g
```

only formats the first line.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
:%s,.*\(\d\d\d\).*\(\d\d\d\).*\(\d\d\d\d\).*,\1 \2 \3,
```

Answer (score 1):

First use count to match a pattern multiple times, it is a bad habbit to repeat the pattern:

```
\d\{3} "instead of \d\d\d
```

Than you also have to match the whitespaces etc:

```
:%s/.*\(\d\{3}\).*\(\d\{3}\).*\(\d\{4}\).*/\1 \2 \3/g
```

Or even better, escape the whole regex with `\v`:

```
:%s/\v.*(\d{3}).*(\d{3}).*(\d{4}).*/\1 \2 \3/g
```

This greatly increases readability

Comment: I tried this originally and it didn't work. Forgot I had to escape the `{` and `}` as well! Damn regex dialects.

Comment: huh why the downvote ? and yeah it is a bit cumbersome but you could use the \v trick to not escape, see my updated answer @ffledgling

Comment: I'm not the one that downvoted, I'm sorry if my comment comes across as criticism, I actually meant it as something I should've done, but didn't. Upvoting for the `\v` trick which I didn't know about.

Comment: @ffledgling Sorry, i didn't meant you with the downvote, hasn't understood it as criticism. But thank you for the upvote, and i wish you a nice day!